# after upgrade to 13.04 unity dash have this blur on my netbook how do i fix it?

Tags: unity

after I upgraded to raring I am experiencing this sort of bug on my unity dash and it's very annoying I searched the web and I can't find anything.  And if I re-size the dash  its still the same.  My net book is a HP mini 110.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Comment: Bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/nux/+bug/1087534

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a blur problem.

Install Unity Tweak Manager.

Choose Unity - Search.

You should change Background Blur from OFF to ON. ( or ON to OFF )

Comment: tnx for the help but may i ask how did that happen?